How can I restore a redshift snapshot using Boto3?
I am trying to restore a Redshift snapshot programmatically, using Boto3 but I am not sure where to get all the details to do that. Here is the documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift/client/restore_from_cluster_snapshot.html
The cluster identifier I set myself so that is fine but I am not sure where to get the snapshot identifier or the ARN (apparently it is one or another). Where can I get these?
Also, do I understand it right that (unless an IAM user has a policy containing a snapshot resource element that specifies anything other than * for the cluster name) no other parameter apart from these are compulsory?
I tried this but it is asking for ARN or snapshot identifier which I don't know:
import boto3
redshift = boto3.client('redshift', 
                        region_name='us-west-2',
                        aws_access_key_id=KEY,
                        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)    
response = redshift.restore_from_cluster_snapshot(
    ClusterIdentifier=DWH_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER) #from a config file


That command will "create a new cluster from a snapshot". The ClusterIdentifier is just a name that you wish to associate with the new cluster. You will also need to provide a SnapshotIdentifier or SnapshotArn so it knows which Snapshot to use. It seems that it also wants a SnapshotClusterIdentifier, which is the "name of the cluster the source snapshot was created from".

Have you tried to first fetch all the snapshot existing for a given cluster then keep one and send its ARN ?
See Boto 3 Doc https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift/client/describe_cluster_snapshots.html
AWS Api Doc :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeClusterSnapshots.html
